# my all value is not showing in view, what can i d

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

This is my edit page where i want to get data from database in input box

```
 @php
     $abs = explode(',' , $order->product);
     $quantitys = explode(',' , $order->quantity);
     foreach (array_combine( $quantitys, $abs) as $quantity => $ab) {
         $val = $ab . "&nbsp;" . $quantity;
         echo "<input type=text name=pro value=$val>";
         echo  $val;
         echo '<br>';
     }
 @endphp
```

This is pic you understand well after see image at bottom of input box this is original value that has to come

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just another thing, you might want to rethink your DB structure, your scenario can be put as one order has many order_product, in this pivot_table you could link the order_id the product_id and note the quantitiy (and if you do partial shipping you could add the status field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite this:

```
echo "<input type=text name=pro value=$val>";
```

to this

```
// add double quotes to attribute values
echo '<input type="text" name="pro" value="'.$val.'">';
```